# How do I exclude an Outlook folder form Windows Search Index in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I have a pretty big (~30GB) email archive (Outlook + Exchange: .ost file) and I would like to use the Outlook Search Feature (Windows Search technology).

I would like to exclude some folders from the indexing (at least the "spam" folder!) but it seems there is no option for that in the standard configurations.

Is there any other way (registries, etc) that can I accomplish this?

I am using Windows 7 and Outlook 2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control which folders in Outlook get indexed its either complete pst or nothing. The Best solution that I could find was, As archived emails are not indexed so I set Auto archived on that directory to be after every 3 days that kept the size of the directory fairly small as a result ignorable indexing overhead