# How do I get Windows Desktop Search (in Windows 7) to index my Exchange mailbox after installing Outlook 2016?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, microsoft-outlook-2016

When I search something into the Windows 7 search box and choose "See more results" as usual a list of found emails and files appears. I can open other file types by double-clicking, but there is no right-mouse menu for Outlook files, and double-clicking doesn't do anything...

With previous Office version this worked fine... I've been through a lot of searches on Google, but none of the pages I read had the right answer... I'm running Windows 7 on a 32-bit computer with Office 2016 Professional Pro...

Comment: You have to move the files into a .PST file for what you describe to happen.  [Circa](http://superuser.com/questions/140669/how-do-i-exclude-an-outlook-folder-form-windows-search-index-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: Actually all files are already "in a pst"... as most of the search results are emails...

Comment: Default outlook file extension for an Exchange mailbox isn't .PST though.